Learning theory of open quantum systems
I'm taking a course on open quantum systems as part of my PhD using the standard textbook by Breur and Petruccione. I was wondering if anyone knows of good complementary material to this book (lectures/books or other resources).
Since I find that BP is at times a bit too technical for me at my current level of understanding.

Try this paper and references therein https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why not ask the person who gives the course?

Some suggestions below.
To understand the basics of quantum maps and non-unitary evolutions from a physical perspective:

Nielsen and Chuang, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information, Cambridge University Press (2010),  https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511976667

From a mathematical perspective on the quantum dynamical semigroup:

Alicki and Kendi, Quantum Dynamical Semigroups and Applications, Springer (2007), https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-70861-8
Gorini, V., Frigerio, A., Verri, M., Kossakowski, A., & Sudarshan, E. C. G. (1978). Properties of quantum Markovian master equations. Reports on Mathematical Physics, 13(2), 149–173. https://doi.org/10.1016/0034-4877(78)90050-2

From a physical perspective on the general theory of open systems (still pretty formal):

Rivas and Huelga, Open Quantum Systems, An Introduction, Springer (2012), https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-23354-8
Lecture notes by Daniel Lidar, http://arxiv.org/abs/1902.00967
Szańkowski, P. (2023). Introduction to the theory of open quantum systems. SciPost Physics Lecture Notes, 68. https://doi.org/10.21468/SciPostPhysLectNotes.68

More specific on open quantum systems out of equilibrium:

Schaller, Open Quantum Systems Far from Equilibrium, Springer (2014), https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-03877-3

GKLS master equation from a physical perspective:

Manzano, D. (2020). A short introduction to the Lindblad master equation. AIP Advances, 10(2), 025106. https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5115323
Chruściński, D., & Pascazio, S. (2017). A Brief History of the GKLS Equation. Open Systems & Information Dynamics, 24(03), 1740001. https://doi.org/10.1142/S1230161217400017

About non-Markovianity:

de Vega, I., & Alonso, D. (2017). Dynamics of non-Markovian open quantum systems. Reviews of Modern Physics, 89(1), 015001. https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.89.015001
Breuer, H.-P., Laine, E.-M., Piilo, J., & Vacchini, B. (2016). Colloquium : Non-Markovian dynamics in open quantum systems. Reviews of Modern Physics, 88(2), 021002. https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.88.021002
Rivas, Á., Huelga, S. F., & Plenio, M. B. (2014). Quantum non-Markovianity: Characterization, quantification and detection. Reports on Progress in Physics, 77(9), 094001. https://doi.org/10.1088/0034-4885/77/9/094001

Physics books with a relevant part about open quantum systems, but from a different perspective (e.g., quantum optics):

Weiss, Quantum Dissipative Systems, World Scientific (2012), https://doi.org/10.1142/8334
Carmichael,  Statistical Methods in Quantum Optics 1 & 2, Springer (1999), https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-03875-8

